# É possível desabilitar a função Onclick para um responsivo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

Tenho uma função onclik que abre uma modal, porém para telas responsivas não fica interessante e resolvi desabilitar em telas abaixo de width de 411px. como desabilito o onclick para esse tamanho de tela?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se tu não estiver usando algum Framework, eu recomendaria apenas ir na função `abreModal()` e evitar que ela aconteça, em telas menores.

```
function abreModal(){
    if(window.outerWidth < 411) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Jardel, coloquei as minhas variáveis dentro de um if >= 768 para o width (width = window.screen.width e height = window.screen.height) valeu pela ajuda :)